# Highlight a matched pattern in a DNA sequence with HTML markup using Perl

Tags: html, perl, cgi, bioinformatics

I am working on generating an HTML page using a CGI script in Perl.

I need filter some sequences in order to check whether they contain a specific pattern; if they contain it I need to print those sequences on my page with 50 bases per line, and highlight the pattern in the sequences. My sequences are in an hash called `%hash`; the keys are the names, the values are the actual sequences.

```
my %hash2;
foreach my $key (keys %hash)  {
    if ($hash{$key} =~ s!(aaagg)!<b>$1</b>!)  {
       $hash2{$key} = $hash{$key}
}
}

foreach my $key (keys %hash2)  {
    print "<p> <b> $key </b> </p>";
    print "<p>$_</p>\n" for unpack '(A50)*', $hash2{$key};
}
```

This method "does" the job however if I highlight the pattern "aaagg" using this method I am messing up the unpacking of the line (`for unpack '(A50)*'`); because now the sequences contains the extra characters of the bold tags which are included in the unpacking count. This beside making the lines of different length it is also a big problem if the tag falls between 2 lines due to unpacking 50 characters, it basically remains open and everything after that is bold.

Comment: Record the position and length of the match, do your unpack, and then insert the tags in the right places. ... You should provide usable sample data and a self-contained script.

Comment: I am sorry I thought the code I reported was enough. I have recorded position and length of the matches; how do I unpack and insert tags in the right places?

Comment: For help on how to formulate a question, see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See also [my answer](/a/44394781/100754).

Answer (score 1):

The script below uses a single randomly generated DNA sequence of length 243 (generated using `http://www.bioinformatics.org/sms2/random_dna.html`) and a variable length pattern.

It works by first recording the positions which need to be highlighted instead of changing the sequence string. The highlighting is inserted after the sequence is split into chunks of 50 bases.

The highlighting is done in reverse order to minimize bookkeeping busy work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML::XS;

my $PRETTY_WIDTH = 50;

# I am using bold-italic so the highlighting
# is visible on Stackoverflow, but in real
# life, this would be something like:
# my @PRETTY_MARKUP = ('<span class="highlighted-match">', '</span>');

my @PRETTY_MARKUP = ('<b><i>', '</i></b>');

use constant { BAŞ => 0, SON => 1, ROW => 0, COL => 1 };

my $sequence = q{ccggtgagacatccagttagttcactgagccgacttgcatcagtcatgcttttccccgtaatgagggccccatattcaggccgtcgtccggaattgtcttggatccggaatgcagcttttctcaccgcttgatgaacattcactgaatatctgacgccgcgaaaacagggtcactagcctgtttccggtcgcccgagaccggcgagtttgtggtatcgcgagcgcccccgggcggtagggtct};

my $wanted = 'c..?gg';

my @pos;

while ($sequence =~ /($wanted)/g) {
    push @pos, [ pos($sequence) - length($1), pos($sequence) ];
}

print Dump \@pos;

my @output = unpack "(A$PRETTY_WIDTH)*", $sequence;

print Dump \@output;

while (my $pos = pop @pos) {
    my @rc = map pos_to_rc($_, $PRETTY_WIDTH), @$pos;
    substr($output[ $rc[$_][ROW] ], $rc[$_][COL], 0, $PRETTY_MARKUP[$_]) for SON, BAŞ;
}

print Dump \@output;

sub pos_to_rc {
    my $r = int( $_[0] / $_[1] );
    my $c = $_[0] - $r * $_[1];
    [ $r, $c ];
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> perl s.pl
---
- - 0
  - 4
- - 76
  - 80
- - 87
  - 91
- - 97
  - 102
- - 104
  - 108
- - 165
  - 170
- - 184
  - 188
- - 198
  - 202
- - 226
  - 231
---
- ccggtgagacatccagttagttcactgagccgacttgcatcagtcatgct
- tttccccgtaatgagggccccatattcaggccgtcgtccggaattgtctt
- ggatccggaatgcagcttttctcaccgcttgatgaacattcactgaatat
- ctgacgccgcgaaaacagggtcactagcctgtttccggtcgcccgagacc
- ggcgagtttgtggtatcgcgagcgcccccgggcggtagggtct
---
- ccggtgagacatccagttagttcactgagccgacttgcatcagtcatgct
- tttccccgtaatgagggccccatattcaggccgtcgtccggaattgtctt
- ggatccggaatgcagcttttctcaccgcttgatgaacattcactgaatat
- ctgacgccgcgaaaacagggtcactagcctgtttccggtcgcccgagacc
- ggcgagtttgtggtatcgcgagcgcccccgggcggtagggtct
```

Especially since this turns out to have been a homework assignment, it is now up to you to take this and apply it to all sequences in your hash table.